# Synchronizing data transfer between client and server

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tcp, server, client

I am working on a client/server tcp project, and I am wondering what a good method for "checking" that the server/client is ready for the data about to be sent.
This is because my client has a gui and I want the server to be ready for any input at any time, and should therefore make sure it isn't trying to send data whilst it is should be sending data

Here is my attempt

Client:

```
import socket
# Methods of a class
def receiveData(self, FROM=""):
    if self.SENT_LAST:
        print("DATA WAS LAST SENT BY CLIENT, NO CHECK REQUIRED")
    else:
        print("DATA LAST SENT BY CLIENT, CHECK REQUIRED")
        self.sendPickledData("dataReady")
    print("In receive data")
    if FROM:
        print("From:", FROM)
    data = s.recv(4096)
    try:
        data = pickle.loads(data)

    except pickle.UnpicklingError as err:
        errorReport(err)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    self.SENT_LAST = False
    if data != noData:
        print("data :",data)
        return data
    else:
        print("No data found")
        return False

def sendPickledData(self, data, FROM=""):
    if self.SENT_LAST:
        print("DATA WAS LAST SENT BY CLIENT, CHECK REQUIRED")
        checkData = self.receiveData("sendpickled")
        print("CheckData :", checkData)
        if checkData != "dataReady":
            raise ValueError
    else:
        print("DATA LAST SENT BY CLIENT, NO CHECK REQUIRED")
    print("In sendPickle, data :", data)
    if FROM:
        print("From:", FROM)
    data = pickle.dumps(data)
    s.sendall(data)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    self.SENT_LAST = True
    print("Data sent")
```

Server:

```
import socket
def receiveData_v2(FROM, FUNC=[]):
    global SENT_LAST, receive_count
    receive_count += 1
    print("Receive :",receive_count)
    print("Receiving")
    if SENT_LAST:
        print("DATA WAS LAST SENT BY SERVER, NO CHECK REQUIRED")
    if not SENT_LAST:
        print("DATA LAST SENT BY SERVER, CHECK REQUIRED")
        sendPickledData("dataReady")
        SENT_LAST = False

    print("In receive data")

    if FROM:
        print("From:", FROM)

    data = conn.recv(4096)

    try:
        data = pickle.loads(data)
    except pickle.UnpicklingError as err:
        print("Pickling error:")
        print(err)

    if data == PROG_QUIT:
        return data
    elif data == noData:
        return False
    else:
        if FUNC:
            funcData = FUNC(data)
            return funcData
        else:
            return data


def sendPickledData(data):
    global SENT_LAST, send_count
    send_count += 1
    print("Send :",send_count)
    print("sending")
    if SENT_LAST:
        print("DATA WAS LAST SENT BY SERVER, CHECK REQUIRED")
        print("sent last")
        checkData = receiveData_v2("sendpickled")
        print("CheckData :", checkData)
        if checkData != "dataReady":
            raise ValueError
    else:
        print("DATA LAST SENT BY SERVER, NO CHECK REQUIRED")
    print("In sendPickled,\nSending:", data)
    data = pickle.dumps(data)
    conn.sendall(data)
    SENT_LAST = True
    conn.sendall(data)
```

Whenever I try to send data via this method, somehow it ends up de-synching and they will both end up trying to listen for data at the same time. Or receiveData (client) will receive only "dataReady"

Comment: I don't understand what the purpose is, sorry? You don't want the program to send data when it is supposed to?

Comment: No. I want a way for my program to check that, when it sends data, the receiver is ready. Because if I send data, then a moment later need to send data again, I want to make sure the receiving end is prepared to receive those two separate pieces of data